# Where can I find literature regarding cardinal invariants of a function space $C(X, Y)$ endowed with the Uniform or Fine topology?

Tags: gn.general-topology, function-spaces

I am working on Function Spaces as a topological space. I want to get a sample paper which studies the cardinal invariants on the function space $C(X, Y)$ rather than on $C(X)$.